# Invalid Bundle - One or more dynamic libraries that are referenced by your app are not present in the dylib search path | Xcode 13.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I am submitting a `.xcarchive` to the App Store via Xcode 13.3 but I keep on getting the following email error:

> ITMS-90562: Invalid Bundle - One or more dynamic libraries that are referenced by your app are not present in the dylib search path

I have tried to look it up and found a couple of solutions, which non of them worked at all.

When using the `otool -L` command on the app itself, I am getting this list of frameworks used:

```
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1300.23.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 60158.100.133)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/SafariServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0, weak)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 5522.2.101)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.11)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1163.100.19)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 331.5.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics (compatibility version 64.0.0, current version 1557.5.4)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1858.112.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/LocalAuthentication.framework/LocalAuthentication (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 985.102.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1331.0.7)
    @rpath/GTProgressBar.framework/GTProgressBar (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @rpath/MBCircularProgressBar.framework/MBCircularProgressBar (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1311.100.3)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AuthenticationServices.framework/AuthenticationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 613.1.17, weak)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Combine.framework/Combine (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 280.101.0, weak)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1858.112.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2667.0.24)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1141.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/MetricKit.framework/MetricKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0, weak)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore (compatibility version 1.2.0, current version 1.11.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0, weak)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework/UserNotifications (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 613.1.17)
    /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftAccelerate.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 29.0.0, weak)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCompression.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.0.0, weak)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 5.6.0)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreData.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 19.0.0, weak)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 14.0.0)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreImage.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.0.0, weak)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 7.0.0, weak)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftDarwin.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftDataDetection.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 697.2.0, weak)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftDispatch.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 11.0.0)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftFileProvider.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 399.100.149, weak)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftFoundation.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 72.105.0)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftMetal.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 261.13.0, weak)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftUIKit.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 5504.0.0)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftUniformTypeIdentifiers.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 722.5.0, weak)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftWebKit.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 613.1.17, weak)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftos.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1023.0.0, weak)
    @rpath/libswift_Concurrency.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 5.6.0, weak)
```

But only these two appear within the `Frameworks` folder:

[image]

As you can see, I have quite a lot of frameworks linked (most of them added via Swift Package Manager). The other 2 `GTProgressBar.xcframework` and `MBCirculaProgressBar.framework` have been added via Carthage. They used to be installed via CocoaPods before and I thought this was the issue. But apparently, it's not.

[image]

I tried setting the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_FRAMEWORKS` flag to `NO` in the project's main target, but it didn't work. Also setting it to `YES` doesn't work.

I am very lost and would love some help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: We're seeing the same error with Xcode 13.3, trying to look for a possible solution

Comment: Just found this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/701949. Hopefully their solution(s) do anything.

Comment: @LuisAscorbe So apparently disabling Bitcode makes it work fine. Horrible.

Comment: came here back to tell you the same  so I guess we're going back to 13.2

Comment: Haha guess so... Apple really needs to stop with these newbie mistakes and wasting people's time

Comment: Having the same. App processing stopped working with Bitcode enabled. Started almost 10 days ago. I don't know why.

Answer (score 5):

It's incredible but at the moment the only solution is disabling bitcode!!! bad bad bad

Comment: That isn't an option if you're bundling an app with a watchOS target.

Comment: Note it seems Bitcode will soon be deprecated